# Swift Alamofire "The request timed out" in one of every two requests

Tags: swift, alamofire

In every one of my two calls to loadHeader with the same URL, I get "The request timed out" error. In first try, the function works and I manage to get and parse the response. In second, I get time out. In third it works and in forth time out again. Is it about my code or about server? I tried waiting before trying again as it might be some security protocol of server but it didn't change anything.

Here is error code:

```
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
```

And here is my code:

```
func loadHeader(url: String){

    let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate { request, response, data in
            // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
            return .success
        }
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            let json=response.data
            self.jsonToObjectHeader(json: json!)
    }
}


func jsonToObjectHeader(json:Data){
    do{
        databases = try JSONDecoder().decode(responseHeader.self,from: json)            
        if databases.ordersHeader.count == 0 {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "empty",message: "empty",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }

        else {
            for i in 0...databases.ordersHeader.count-1 {
                myArray2.append(databases.ordersHeader[i].productName!)
            }
        }


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
            self.myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        }

        //print(databases.ordersHeader[0].companyAddress)
    }catch let jsonErr {
        print(jsonErr)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the network side with something like CharlesProxy? If it's coming back with a timeout error then it sounds like it's probably a server thing.

Comment: I think its server issue, not of Alamofire

Comment: Just try with the postman whether it works fine or not.

Comment: I just tried it with Postman and server works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

```
let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
```

thinking I've to give parameters as it is in the function. Just updated

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

to

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

and it solved the issue. Posting this in case of someone experiences something similar.